# draw calayers paths without hiding lower layers

Tags: ios, uikit, calayer

What I'm trying to achieve is to draw a red square perimeter on top of radar lik[e screen made of 2 perpendicular lines t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abFMe.jpg)o get the 4 quadrants and 10 green concentric circles each one as a UIBezierPath on its own CAShapeLayer and then to superpose on top of them a red square perimeter.

What I'm getting though is that the perimeter layer is "covering" the underlying layers of green lines. The only way to display both the red square perimeter and the underlying circles has been to define the perimeter.opacity = 0.5. This way both the red perimeter and the green lines are visible but the side effect is that the both loose opacity whilst I want their paths to be fully opaque and their backgrounds ( the parts of each layer that don't contain the path) to be transparent.
Note that I have set the background color of each path as UIColor.clear.cgColor, but this doesn't' seem to have any effect.
There should be an easy solution for something so simple!

!!!!!UPDATE!!!!!

You can easily reproduce the issue copying and pasting to the playground. Make sure you open the assistant editor and you will see the drawings

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground
import PlaygroundSupport

var plottingPanel = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100.0, y: 0.0, width: 375.0, height: 375.0))

let plottingPanelHeight = plottingPanel.bounds.size.height
let plottingPanelWidth = plottingPanel.bounds.size.width
let originX = plottingPanel.bounds.size.width/2
let originY = plottingPanel.bounds.size.height/2
let originPoint = CGPoint(x: originX, y: originY)
let west = CGPoint(x: 0,y: originY)
let east = CGPoint(x: plottingPanelWidth,y: originY)
let north = CGPoint(x :originX,y: 0)
let sud = CGPoint(x: originX,y: plottingPanelHeight)

let radius = plottingPanelWidth/2

//Draw Circles

let circles = 10
for i in 0..<circles{
    let circle1Layer = CAShapeLayer()
    let circleRadius = (radius/CGFloat(circles)) * CGFloat(circles - i)
    circle1Layer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: originPoint, radius: circleRadius , startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true ).cgPath
    circle1Layer.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    circle1Layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    circle1Layer.lineWidth = 1
    plottingPanel.layer.addSublayer(circle1Layer)
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = plottingPanel
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
// Draw Quadrants
let bezierPathQuadrants = UIBezierPath()
bezierPathQuadrants.move(to: west)
bezierPathQuadrants.addLine(to: east)
bezierPathQuadrants.move(to: north)
bezierPathQuadrants.addLine(to: sud)

let cross = CAShapeLayer()
cross.path = bezierPathQuadrants.cgPath
cross.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
cross.lineWidth = 1
cross.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
cross.isOpaque = true
plottingPanel.layer.addSublayer(cross)


// Draw Perimeter
var perimeterRectSideMts = CGFloat(400)
func ptsFromCm(_ cm: Float) -> CGFloat{
    let maxRadius = CGFloat(1000) // cm
    return   (plottingPanelHeight / (2 * maxRadius) ) * CGFloat(cm)     // 6,25
}

let sideMts = Float(perimeterRectSideMts/2)
let sidePts = ptsFromCm(sideMts)
let pointA = CGPoint(x: (originPoint.x - sidePts) , y: (originPoint.y - sidePts) )
let pointB = CGPoint(x: originPoint.x + sidePts, y: originPoint.y - sidePts)
let pointC = CGPoint(x: originPoint.x - sidePts, y: originPoint.y + sidePts)
let pointD = CGPoint(x: originPoint.x + sidePts, y: originPoint.y + sidePts)

let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
bezierPath.move(to: pointA)
bezierPath.addLine(to: pointB)
bezierPath.addLine(to: pointD)
bezierPath.addLine(to: pointC)
bezierPath.close()

let perimeter = CAShapeLayer()
perimeter.path = bezierPath.cgPath
perimeter.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
perimeter.lineWidth = 2
perimeter.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
perimeter.isOpaque = false
perimeter.opacity = 0.5

// Tried this with no luck
var maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.frame = perimeter.bounds;
maskLayer.path = perimeter.path
perimeter.mask = maskLayer;

plottingPanel.layer.addSublayer(perimeter)
```

Comment: This should work, as written. What does it look like when `perimeter.opacity = 1.0`?

Comment: The effect of setting perimeter.opacity = 1.0 is that the perimeter square is drawn with a more solid color but the empty space inside the square perimeter will totally hide the underlying green circles. The opaqueness seems to be applied to the whole layer area. There must be a way to mask out the empty space

Comment: The default should be fine, but can you ensure that `perimeter.isOpaque` is indeed `false`?

Comment: perimeter.isOpaque is true and doesn't make any difference.I have edited the post it's easy to see it in the playground, just copy the code and drop it in a playground!

Comment: No, it needs to be *false*! If it's `true`, that's your problem!

Comment: it's false as you can see from the code posted, it was my mistake typing the comment, sorry

Comment: I think the solution has to to with the perimeter.mask property. I have tried this with no luck:
    var maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = perimeter.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = perimeter.path

   perimeter.mask = maskLayer;